# Set x-axis to non-monotonic values and avoid scaling

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis-labels

I use matlab to plot a graph where instead of having x-axis increase monotonically, I have my own values. eg 5 14 8 9 12 7 etc.I use `set (gca,'XTickLabel',num2str(mydata))` which generally works. However, when mydata is more than four or five digits, Matlab scales the graph and thus x-axis values no longer correspond to their intended points.  Any ideas on how to prevent this scaling? To clarify, when I make the figure larger, it shows the plot as it should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `num2str()` conversion:

```
mydata = 1:10;
num2str(mydata)
ans = 
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

This means, that each tick will be labelled with this long 1 by n char array. The axes will then be resized to fit the labels inside the figure.

A solution is to create one label per **row** of a char array:

```
reshape(sprintf('%2d',mydata),2,[])'
ans =
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

Answer (score -1):

Sort of solution is to write `set(gca,'xtick',1:myDataVectorLength)` before `set (gca,'XTickLabel',num2str(mydata))`

Comment: This cannot be correct. I am unsure how that solves your issue and would like to see an example.